# data type of results of java arithmetic calculation

Tags: java, math, type-conversion

In java, I know the data type of the result of an arithmetic calculation depends on the data types of the numbers involved in the calculation. 
For example,

1. int + int = int
2. long/double=double

a. But I can't find any references which can give me all these rules. Could someone help me?

b. How to avoid over flow in arithmetic calculation? For example, the results of 2 long may not fit into a long anymore...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a. These rules are called numeric promotion rules and are specified in [Java Language Specification, §5.6.2 *(currently)*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

b.  There are two generally accepted method for dealing with overflows.

The first method, a post-check, where you do an operation, say addition and then check that the result is greater than either of the operands.  For example:

```
int c = a + b;

if( c<a) {  // assuming a>=0 and b>=0
   // overflow happened
}
```

The second method, is a pre-check, where you basically try to avoid the overflow from happening in the first place.  Example:

```
if( a > Integer.MAX_INTERGER - b ) {
   // overflow happened
}
```

Comment: Your first check isn't always valid. If b is negative, `c < a` will be true without overflow.

Comment: That's true.  I'll add that to the example.  But I'm just illustrating the approach, not giving a foolproof solution.

Comment: Ya, I know that isn't a full solution. I just wanted to point that out so poster didn't take it as verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

The specific section of the Java Language Specification that deals with these rules is [section 4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2).

If you don't want values to overflow at all, use a `BigInteger` or some other arbitrary-precision arithmetic type.

For avoiding overflows in the general case, [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) (which I contribute to) provides methods like [`IntMath.checkedAdd(int, int)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html#checkedAdd%28int,%20int%29) and [`LongMath.checkedMultiply(long, long)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/math/LongMath.html#checkedMultiply%28long,%20long%29), which throw exceptions on overflow.  (Some of those are nontrivial to implement yourself, but these are all *very* exhaustively tested.)  You can look at the source to see how they work, but most of them rely on cute bit-twiddling tricks to check for overflow efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

The result of an arithmetic operation on any two primitive integer operands will be at least an int -- even if the operands are bytes and short.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question A:

The type of operand with the "larger type"

[image]

Double is the "largest" type

Note: char and boolean cannot be used w/ arithmetic operator

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-java-examples/